# How do I set CRYPT_FORCE_KEY_PROTECTION_HIGH to enforce high-level strong private key protection for RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, cryptography, pinvoke

**EDIT:** I was passing CRYPT_FORCE_KEY_PROTECTION_HIGH to the wrong function as pointed out by Luke. I also had an incorrect value for the flag. After making both these corrections the user gets a pop-up to set the key protection password, but the password isn't being required when the key is accessed. I am still trying to troubleshoot why not.

I am importing a public certificate and private key into .NET as a .pfx file. I want to add the certificate to the current user certificate store with high-level strong private key protection enforced(user has to enter a password when the certificate is added to the store, the password is required when the key is accessed). I know there is a flag I can use to set high protection - `CRYPT_FORCE_KEY_PROTECTION_HIGH`.

I am trying to create a copy of the private key with the flag set on the key container, and then attach that private key to a copy of the public key from the certificate.

This code runs with no exceptions or errors. The certificate and private key are added to the store, and they work for encryption/decryption. But strong key protection is not enabled at all and there is no pop-up.

```
// certData is obtained from an existing certificate with X509Certificate2.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx)
public static void AddCertificateStrongKeyProtection(byte[] certData)
{
    using (X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certData, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet))
    {
        IntPtr hProv = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr hKey = IntPtr.Zero;

        const string providerName = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
        const string containerName = "HighProtectionContainer";

        // Acquire a cryptographic context with the flag for strong protection set
        if (!NCrypt.CryptAcquireContext(ref hProv, containerName, providerName, NCrypt.PROV_RSA_FULL, NCrypt.CRYPT_NEWKEYSET))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        const uint AT_KEYEXCHANGE = 1;
        const uint CRYPT_FORCE_KEY_PROTECTION_HIGH = 0x00008000;

        // Make a new key
        if (!NCrypt.CryptGenKey(hProv, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, CRYPT_FORCE_KEY_PROTECTION_HIGH, ref hKey))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        // Convert the original RSACng to RSACryptoServiceProvider by exporting/importing RSA params
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters parameters = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey().ExportParameters(true);
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(parameters);

        // Get the handle of the RSACryptoServiceProvider
        var keyField = typeof(RSACryptoServiceProvider).GetField("_safeKeyHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (keyField == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to access the _safeKeyHandle field.");
        }

        var safeKeyHandle = (SafeHandle)keyField.GetValue(rsaCryptoServiceProvider);
        IntPtr originalKey = safeKeyHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

        const uint PRIVATEKEYBLOB = 0x7;
        int blobLength = 0;

        // Export the original key data
        if (!NCrypt.CryptExportKey(originalKey, IntPtr.Zero, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, null, ref blobLength))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        byte[] keyBlob = new byte[blobLength];

        if (!NCrypt.CryptExportKey(originalKey, IntPtr.Zero, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, keyBlob, ref blobLength))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        // Import the original key data into the newly created key
        if (!NCrypt.CryptImportKey(hProv, keyBlob, keyBlob.Length, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out hKey))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters
        {
            ProviderType = (int)NCrypt.PROV_RSA_FULL,
            KeyContainerName = "HighProtectionContainer",  // Should be the same as used in step 2
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey
         };

         RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
         using (X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificate.RawData))
         {
             X509Certificate2 newCert = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaProvider)

             using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
             {
                 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                 store.Add(newCert);
                 store.Close();
             }
         }
    }             
}
```

My P/Invoke signatures:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(
    ref IntPtr hProv,
    string pszContainer,
    string pszProvider,
    uint dwProvType,
    uint dwFlags);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CryptGenKey(
    IntPtr hProv,
    uint Algid,
    uint dwFlags,
    ref IntPtr phKey);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptExportKey(
    IntPtr hKey, 
    IntPtr hExpKey, 
    uint dwBlobType, 
    uint dwFlags, 
    byte[] pbData, 
    ref int pdwDataLen);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptImportKey(
    IntPtr hProv,
    byte[] pbData,
    int dwDataLen,
    IntPtr hPubKey,
    uint dwFlags,
    out IntPtr phKey);
```

Comment: You're passing the flag to the wrong function.

Comment: @Luke could you elaborate? If I pass the flag to CryptGenKey I get an "invalid flags specified" exception, but all the sources I have found indicate the flag should be valid for CAPI. `CryptGenKey(hProv, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, 0x00000040, ref hKey)` causes an exception.

Comment: I found a different value for `CRYPT_FORCE_KEY_PROTECTION_HIGH`. If I set it to `0x00008000` the `CryptGenKey` works, and the user gets a popup to set a password for the key. However, the password isn't being required when the key is accessed for decryption. When I created and added the key to the store with CNG, the password was required when the key was accessed. I'm not sure why this is different.

Comment: You probably need to set a flag on `CryptImportKey()` to tell the CSP to protect the key. It isn't documented as supporting `CRYPT_FORCE_KEY_PROTECTION_HIGH` but I'd give that a shot anyway. If that fails, you can try `CRYPT_USER_PROTECTED`.